# In the arm-none-eabi-gdb simulator, ldr from the program entry point seems to give nonsensical result

Tags: assembly, arm, gdb

I am learning to program in ARM assembly for a bare metal raspberry pi.
I run `arm-none-eabi-gdb` on my x86 machine for debugging.
The simulator that comes with `arm-none-eabi-gdb` does not behave as I would have expected on the following simple program:

```
.section ".text.startup"

.global _start

_start:
    nop
    nop
    nop
    ldr     r0, =_start
    ldr     r2, [r0]
    ldr     r3, [r0, #4]
    ldr     r4, [r0, #8]
```

I expect the code for `nop` to be loaded into registers `r2`, `r3` and `r4`. However, when I compiled the program

```
$ arm-none-eabi-gcc -mfloat-abi=hard -nostartfiles -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a7 -O0 test.S -o kernel.elf
```

to get

```
$ arm-none-eabi-objdump -S kernel.elf

kernel.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00004000 <_start>:
    4000:   e320f000    nop {0}
    4004:   e320f000    nop {0}
    4008:   e320f000    nop {0}
    400c:   e59f0008    ldr r0, [pc, #8]    ; 401c <_start+0x1c>
    4010:   e5902000    ldr r2, [r0]
    4014:   e5903004    ldr r3, [r0, #4]
    4018:   e5904008    ldr r4, [r0, #8]
    401c:   00004000    .word   0x00004000
```

and run it inside the simulator in `arm-none-eabi-gdb`, the registers `r3` and `r4` got loaded with `0xe320f000`, which is correct.
However `r2` is loaded with `0xe7ffdefe`, which does not seem to be from anywhere.

I have `arm-none-eabi-gdb` version 7.8.1 and `arm-none-eabi-gcc` version 4.8.3. Is this a bug in the simulator or am I missing something obvious?

P.s. I tried to change the entry point to `0x4000` instead of the default `0x8000` in the link script. The problem persists, so somehow the simulator doesn't load from the entry point memory address properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a breakpoint set at `_start:`?  `0xe7ffdefe` is probably the machine instruction for a software breakpoint that GDB overwrote the first `nop` with, to implement the breakpoint.

You can reproduce this on x86 with `_start: mov edi, [rel _start]`, and the low byte of RDI will be either `0xcc` (`int3`) or `0x8b` (the opcode for `mov r32, r/m32`) depending on whether you have a breakpoint set at `_start` or not.

---

**GDB doesn't try to fake out code that reads itself to stop it from seeing software breakpoints**.  You can get GDB to use hardware breakpoints to work around this.  Use `hbreak` instead of `break`  (https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Breaks.html)

But GDB does hide this from `x /i` or `disas` GDB commands, presenting the illusion of the unmodified code bytes.

---

BTW, **you can use `starti` to run the program but stop before the first instruction executes**.  (i.e. set a temporary breakpoint at the entry point, with the advantage that it works even if there's no label at the entry point.)

Then you can single-step (which doesn't involve setting SW breakpoints either), and your code will execute as expected.

Comment: Thank you! This makes a lot of sense. I did set a breakpoint at `_start`, and checked `x/x 0x8000` afterwards repeatedly like a fool. Btw I checked that `starti` isn't available in my `arm-none-eabi-gdb` version 7.8.1, but is in 8.2.1.